# Keep accordion tab active when returned to page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an accordion with links to subpages within the tabs content.

When the user navigates back from the subpage unto the homepage either by the browser's back arrow, or by a homepage link that will be on the subpage I would like the tab that led them to that page to be open.

link to the jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/tqpj1t0w/4/

Code:

```
$('#accordion').find('.accordion-toggle').click(function (){

  //Expand or collapse this panel
  $(this).next().toggleClass('active');

  //Hide the other panels
  $(".accordion-content").not($(this).next()).removeClass('active');});



<div id="accordion">
      <section>
        <h2 class="accordion-toggle">test 1</h2>
          <div class="accordion-content">
        <a href="#">subpage link</a>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
           </div>
      </section>
      <section>
        <h2 class="accordion-toggle">test 2</h2>
          <div class="accordion-content">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
           </div>
      </section>
      <section>
        <h2 class="accordion-toggle">test 3</h2>
          <div class="accordion-content">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
           </div>
      </section>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using cookies or [local storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

When clicking an accordion save the index of the active one

```
$('#accordion').find('.accordion-toggle').click(function (){

      localStorage.setItem("accordion", $(this).closest('section').index());
      localStorage.removeItem("accordion");
      //Expand or collapse this panel
      $(this).next().toggleClass('active');

      //Hide the other panels
      $(".accordion-content").not($(this).next()).removeClass('active');
  });
```

then on document.ready function read that attribute and activate the accordion

```
var activeAccordion = localStorage.getItem("accordion");
  if(activeAccordion){
    $('#accordion section:eq('+activeAccordion+') .accordion-content').toggleClass('active');
  }
```

see [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tqpj1t0w/7/)

Comment: This kind of works.. only problem is that if I were to have a tab open and return to the website at a later date it will still have that tab open.
I just need it to have it open when you navigate back to the homepage from a secondary page - is that possible?
Also, is there a way to make the browser scroll down to the open tab when this happens? Thanks :)

Comment: @danik sure, you can remove the localstorage item after you read it, so the next time it won't open again: `localStorage.removeItem("accordion");` I updated the answer and the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tqpj1t0w/7/), check out

Comment: that's awesome thanks a lot! works like a charm. Just a side question - would you happen to know of a way to scroll to the open tab when returned to the page?

Comment: yep @danik , you can use `scrollTop` function. check this updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tqpj1t0w/9/ . Note that in the example i used `html` and `body` as scrollable container, but you may have another.. in that case change the selector ;)

Answer (score 1):

There is a two way :

1)  you just put the id to header and get the id of Active tab in **localStorage** and check when you are returning to that same page.

ex:

```
localStorage.setItem("activeTab", "test1");

 if(localStorage!=null)
 {
var activeTabId =  localStorage.getItem("activeTab")
$('#accordion').find(activeTabId).addClass('active');
}
```

2) **use query-string instead and check when to returning to that page.**

I hope it help.

Comment: Problem with localstorage is same as the comment I posted on pumpkinz' answer. Would a query string still have the same issue and how would you approach it using a query string? Thanks :)